# How can I only choose 1 subnet on my DB instance with multiple subnet in VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, subnet, vpc

I have a DB Instance restored via snapshot in AWS and a VPC which has 6 subnets, but I only need 1 subnet on my new instance. Is it possible without creating new VPC?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Jned,

1. You can create new Subnet Group and select the required subnets. [image]
2. Select the specific subnet group while creating DB Instance.

   **Please Note:** You can't select 1 Subnet. You'll need at least two subnets in two different availability zones since RDS required this for Multi-AZ mainly.

Thanks!

Comment: Hassan Murtaza, we are on the same page, that is actually my concern. I need to select only 1 subnet. So it's not possible? :(

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be possible atm. I'm sorry.